# Setting and Initializing multiple knockout view models

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, viewmodel, knockout-mvc

I am trying to create and initialize some sort of master view model that contains common view models that might be run on every page and page specific models that are appended on page load.

```
var MasterViewModel = {
   commonViewModel1 : CommonViewModel1(),
   commonViewModel2 : CommonViewModel1()
};

var commonInit = function() {
  // Populate View Model Data
  MasterViewModel.commonViewModel1 = initCommonViewModel1();
  MasterViewModel.commonViewModel2 = initCommonViewModel2();

  // Apply common view model bindings
  ko.applyBindings(MasterViewModel);
};

var pageSpecificInit = function() {
  // Populate Specific View Model Data
  MasterViewModel.pageViewModel1 = initPageViewModel1();
  MasterViewModel.pageViewModel2 = initPageViewModel2();

 // Apply Page Specific Bindings
 ko.applyBindings(MasterViewModel);
};

$(function() {
  commonInit();
  pageSpecificInit();
});
```

this is a crude example of what I am trying to do in the real application this is all namespaced and in separate files so that only page specific code is run. What is the best practice for doing this I somewhat based the above on http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/quick-tip-skip-binding.html but when I do it in the application I get something like "cannot bind to pageViewModel1 undefined" should I setup my MasterViewModel differently to be more like

```
var MasterViewModel = {
   commonViewModel1 : CommonViewModel1(),
   commonViewModel2 : CommonViewModel1(),
   pageViewModels : {}
};

    var commonInit = function() {
  // Populate View Model Data
  MasterViewModel.commonViewModel1 = initCommonViewModel1();
  MasterViewModel.commonViewModel2 = initCommonViewModel2();

  // Apply common view model bindings
  ko.applyBindings(MasterViewModel);
};

var pageSpecificInit = function() {
  // Populate Specific View Model Data
  MasterViewModel.pageViewModels.pageViewModel1 = initPageViewModel1();
  MasterViewModel.pageViewModels.pageViewModel2 = initPageViewModel2();

 // Apply Page Specific Bindings
 ko.applyBindings(MasterViewModel.pageViewModels);
};

$(function() {
  commonInit();
  pageSpecificInit();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second example is more correct, but shouldn't you be binding the page-specific view models to a specific html element that you've surrounded with the stop binding comment?

```
ko.applyBindings(MasterViewModel.pageViewModels, $('#pageElement')[0]);
```

However, if you want to have nicely decoupled objects that can talk to each other, then you might want to look at [Knockout Postbox](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox/)

Comment: well then I am limited to certain parts of the page for certain bindings it is possible that I would want to do something inside a foreach for pageViewModel2.items I want to click a button like $root.commonViewModel1.updateCustomerTotal. I dont see the case for stopping and starting bindings all over the place.

Comment: I must admit, I'm struggling to fully envisage what you're after here, but I've updated my answer with some further information.

Comment: sorry I am new to knockout so mb what I am talking about is a bit strange. I guess I am just trying to bind multiple view models on a page without any references to DOM elements in the initialization

Comment: That's alright, no need to apologise! I can't say for certain, but I really don't think that you can bind multiple models to the whole page. You can have one view model with multiple sub-view models, that should work, so I'd debug and see what your MasterViewModel contains. It sounds like you have a different issue.